Get all of the documents for user in elastic enterprise search
I would like to get all of the documents for a user in elastic enterprise search using @elastic/enterprise-search npm package.
The only way i had some success was using client.app.search() using empty string for query but it seems unreliable and i am trying to look for another way to do it.
Elastic currently in use is 8.12.1 i can upgrade if needed
Thanks in advance
